# Batch replace multiple placeholder images with with warp/smart object filters

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing, smartobject

In the process of looking for an answer to my question I came across this thread here: [Batch replace placeholder image with a perspective warp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136622/batch-replace-placeholder-image-with-a-perspective-warp)

This is essentially what I'm trying to do, except for multiple images instead of just one.

Before I try to learn how to write a script myself (and potentially waste my time), would anybody with a bit more experience know if this is even possible in the first place?

I've worked with variables a lot, but they don't seem to work with Smart Object layers, or am I doing something wrong there?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

**Edit** Here are a couple of images of the sort of thing I'm hoping to do.
[image: Swedish Hockey League versus]

[image: Swedish Hockey League versus]

Comment: "Multiple images" or multiple smart object *layers* in *one* image?

Comment: @Scott So I'm looking to make versus graphics for sports events, so I'll need to use two teams' logos minimum, but it'd be great if more elements could be used. I'll update my post with a couple of examples I found that are similar to what I want to do.